# Como utilizar o mesmo código ZPL em impressoras com dpi diferentes

Tags: c#

Caros,

Há algum tempo venho utilizando o software ZebraDesigner2 para criar etiquetas em ZPL para impressão na GC420t e não estou tendo problemas.
Agora tenho que gerar código ZPL para impressão de etiquetas utilizando as impressoras S4M (200 dpi) e ZT230 (300 dpi) o problema é a diferença de dpi das mesmas, que faz com que a impressão feita pela S4M saia muito grande cortando informações importantes.

Ex:

```
^XA
^PW1240
^LL1724
^FT321,845^A0N,42,40^FH\^FDTeste 1234567890^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

Já tentei utilizar os comandos abaixo, porem não encontrei bons exemplos.

```
^MU – Set Units of Measurement
^JM – Set Dots per Millimeter
```

Preciso que a impressão em ambas as impressoras sejam iguais não importa que seja em 200 ou 300 dpi.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

E se você mostrar uma tela para o usuário escolher a impressora e você cria uma configuração dinâmica na geração do código ZPL? Assim não daria certo?

Answer (score 0):

Fiz da seguinte forma, mantenho um cadastro de impressoras onde tenho a informação de DPI da mesma e crio todos os meus templates zpl no padrão 300 DPI quando é necessário converto de 300 para 200 DPI com a função abaixo, já estou utilizando a há pelo menos 5 meses e está servindo muito bem.

Só não consigo converter imagens :(

```
public static string RemoveNonNumbers(this string source) {
 return Regex.Replace(source, @ "[^0-9]+", "");
}

public static string ConvertTo200DPI(string zplCommands) {
 string cmdReady = string.Empty;

 using(StringReader reader = new StringReader(zplCommands)) {
  string[] keyCmds = {
   "FT",
   "A0I",
   "A0R",
   "GB",
   "FO",
   "BY",
   "A0N",
   "FB"
  };

  string line;
  while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
   string newLine = line;
   const decimal ActualDpi = 300 m;
   const decimal ExpectedDpi = 200 m;

   string[] cmds = line.Split('^');
   foreach(var cmd in cmds) {
    if (keyCmds.Any(x => cmd.Replace("^", "").Contains(x))) {
     string oldValue = string.Empty;
     string newValue = string.Empty;

     string[] values = cmd.Split(',');
     if (values.Length >= 1) {
      if (!keyCmds.Any(x => values[0] == x)) {
       string val = values[0].RemoveNonNumbers();
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val)) {
        newValue = ((int)((Convert.ToInt32(val) / ActualDpi) * ExpectedDpi)).ToString();
       }
       oldValue = values[0].RemoveNonNumbers();
      }
     }
     if (values.Length >= 2) {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldValue)) {
       newValue += ",";
       oldValue += ",";
      }

      string val = values[1].RemoveNonNumbers();
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val)) {
       newValue += ((int)((Convert.ToInt32(val) / ActualDpi) * ExpectedDpi));
      }
      oldValue += values[1].RemoveNonNumbers();
     }
     if (values.Length >= 3) {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldValue)) {
       newValue += ",";
       oldValue += ",";
      }
      string val = values[2].RemoveNonNumbers();
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val)) {
       newValue += ((int)((Convert.ToInt32(values[2].RemoveNonNumbers()) / ActualDpi) * ExpectedDpi));
      }
      oldValue += values[2].RemoveNonNumbers();
     }

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldValue)) newLine = newLine.Replace(cmd, cmd.Replace(oldValue, newValue));
    }
   }

   cmdReady += newLine + System.Environment.NewLine;
  }
 }

 return cmdReady;
}
```